# Static call on a twig filter

Tags: symfony, filter, twig

I'm trying to get a twig filter that would sort entities by score. My City class got a score attribute with getters and setters, and I created this extension :

```
<?php

namespace AOFVH\HomepageBundle\Twig;
use Twig_Extension, Twig_SimpleFilter, Twig_Environment;

class ScoreExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        $filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('score', array('AOFVH\FlyBundle\Entity\City', 'getScore'))
    );
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'score_extension';
}
}
```

which I call like this :

```
        {% for cit in cities|score %}
      <a href="{{ path('aofvh_city', {'name': cit.name}) }}">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <img src="{{ asset('Cities/'~cit.name~'.png') }}" class="img" alt="Cinque Terre" width="300" height="300">
        <h2>{{cit.name}}</h2>
        </div>
      </a>

        {% endfor %}
```

But for some reason, I cannot get it rendered, instead I git this error

```
 ContextErrorException: Runtime Notice: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method AOFVH\FlyBundle\Entity\City::getScore() should not be called statically
```

Did I miss something ?

Comment: Do you want go get the score of the city in a twig template? can you show us the call of the filter in your template please

Comment: I just added my call

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but can't you just do `{% for cit in cities.getScore() %}` ?

Comment: If  the @Brewal answer doesn't work, please post the content of `AOFVH\FlyBundle\Entity\City` because there is a piece of logic i don't get

Comment: The error said : "non-static method AOFVH\FlyBundle\Entity\City::getScore() should not be called statically"... So your method is not static !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `Twig_SimpleFilter`'s constructor requires a `callable`.

If you pass it a class name and a method name, it will call that method of that class statically:

`array('SomeClass', 'someMethod')`

If you, instead, pass it an instance of a class and a method name, it will call that method inside the object:

`array($this->someInstance, 'someMethod')`

This means that you either make `getScore()` static or you create an instance of `City` and use that (maybe get it using *Dependency Injection*).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do something like this, using the actual variable beeing filtered. Here, I guess that `cities` is a Collection :

```
class ScoreExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            $filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('score', array($this, 'getCityScore'))
        );
    }

    public function getCityScore($cities)
    {
        $scores = array();

        foreach ($cities as $city) {
            $scores[] = $city->getScore();
        }

        return $scores;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'score_extension';
    }

}
```